# "The configuration failed" ./waf when build bootloader

Tags: c++, c, build, compiler-errors, bootloader

I'm trying to compile pyinstaller from source, it worked until 3 months ago, I didn't make any changes in Visual Studio and buildtools, but now it doesn't work at all.

```
C:\Users\caiop\Downloads\pyinstaller-5.13.0\bootloader>python ./waf all --target-arch=64bit
'all' finished successfully (0.001s)
'distclean' finished successfully (0.000s)
Setting top to                           : C:\Users\caiop\Downloads\pyinstaller-5.13.0\bootloader
Setting out to                           : C:\Users\caiop\Downloads\pyinstaller-5.13.0\bootloader\build
Python Version                           : 3.10.10 (tags/v3.10.10:aad5f6a, Feb  7 2023, 17:20:36) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Checking for 'msvc' (C compiler)         : not found
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : not found
Checking for 'clang' (C compiler)        : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin\clang.exe
Platform                                 : Windows-64bit manually chosen
Checking for compiler flags -m64         : yes
Checking for linker flags -m64           : no
The configuration failed
(complete log in C:\Users\caiop\Downloads\pyinstaller-5.13.0\bootloader\build\config.log)
```

[Log Download](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1thE2LGITOZmzoo8039I-kh4txYlpYK7b)

I got this from: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/releases/tag/v5.13.0

Tested with VS19 and VS22